# Project Time Scaled Data VBA Use

Tags: vba, time, project

Using the API I am looking to populate a spead sheet with some time scaled data from pjTaskTimescaledBaselineRemainingTasks how ever it is faliing over.

I want to go through the prject and pull date,  pjTaskTimescaledBaselineRemainingTasks,pjTaskTimescaledRemainingTasks and pjTaskTimescaledRemainingActualTasks so I can create a burndown chart.

Orginally I though pjTaskTimescaledBaselineRemainingTasks was part of the application.resources object but I'm not so sure now.

I know .Start (which I also need in the same sheet) is part of aplication.tasks.

I assume this is failing as I am not addressing the feild correctly ie its not T.PjTaskTimescaledData.pjTaskTimescaledBaselineRemainingTasks.

Can any one assist as I have looked at the api documenation but do not fully understand how this nesting works yet ?

Thanks

Terran

```
Set Pj = ActiveProject

For Each T In Pj.Tasks

XlSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = T.Start
XlSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value = T.PjTaskTimescaledData(pjTaskTimescaledBaselineRemainingTasks)

Next T
```

UPDATED Code based on Malcolm's feed back

```
Sub GetFinishesPerDay()
'Malcolm Farrelle
Const DateValue = 0
Const BLFinish = 1
Const FFinish = 2
Const ACFinish = 3
Dim TaskFinishes() As Date
Dim FinishesPerDate() As Variant
Dim t As Task
Dim p As Project
Dim x As Integer
Dim startdt As Date
Dim finishdt As Date
Dim dt As Date
Dim ThisIndex As Integer
ReDim TaskFinishes(4, 0)
ReDim FinishesPerDate(3, 0)
Set p = ActiveProject
startdt = p.Finish
finishdt = p.Start

Set XlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets("Burndown_Data")
XlSheet.Activate
xlApp.StatusBar = "Updating Burndown Data"

'and the column headings in row 2
XlSheet.Cells(2, 2).Value = "Date"
XlSheet.Cells(3, 2).Value = "Baseline Remaining Tasks" 'BLFinish
XlSheet.Cells(4, 2).Value = "Remaining Tasks" 'FFinish
XlSheet.Cells(5, 2).Value = "Remaining Actual Tasks"


i = 3

'Malcolm Farrelle
For Each t In p.Tasks
    If Not t Is Nothing Then
        'Do not consider any "blank lines" in the project, these are not actually tasks and code will fail
        If Not t.Summary Then
            'Check the finish and baselinefinish dates and set the "startdt" and "finishdt"
            'variables with the earliest start and latest finish of the whole data set
            If t.Finish < startdt Then startdt = t.Finish
            If t.Finish > finishdt Then finishdt = t.Finish
            If t.BaselineFinish <> "NA" Then
                If t.BaselineFinish < startdt Then startdt = t.BaselineFinish
                If t.BaselineFinish > finishdt Then finishdt = t.BaselineFinish
            End If

            'Consider only non-summary tasks - if required add another check to exclude milestones
            ThisIndex = UBound(TaskFinishes, 2) + 1
            ReDim Preserve TaskFinishes(3, ThisIndex)
            If t.BaselineFinish <> "NA" Then TaskFinishes(BLFinish, ThisIndex) = t.BaselineFinish
            TaskFinishes(FFinish, ThisIndex) = t.Finish
            If t.ActualFinish <> "NA" Then TaskFinishes(ACFinish, ThisIndex) = t.ActualFinish
        End If
    End If
Next t


'construct an array of Finishes and Baseline Finishes per date
For dt = Format(startdt, "dd/mmm/yy") To Format(finishdt, "dd/mmm/yy")
    'Using "Format" removes the "HH:MM" component of the itterating "dt" date
    ThisIndex = UBound(FinishesPerDate, 2) + 1
    ReDim Preserve FinishesPerDate(4, ThisIndex)
    FinishesPerDate(FFinish, ThisIndex) = 0
    FinishesPerDate(BLFinish, ThisIndex) = 0
    FinishesPerDate(ACFinish, ThisIndex) = 0
    For x = 1 To UBound(TaskFinishes, 2)
        FinishesPerDate(DateValue, ThisIndex) = dt
        If TaskFinishes(BLFinish, x) <> 0 Then
            'task (i) has a baseline finish
            If TaskFinishes(BLFinish, x) >= dt And TaskFinishes(BLFinish, x) < dt + 1 Then
                'and it finishes on date "dt"
                FinishesPerDate(BLFinish, ThisIndex) = FinishesPerDate(BLFinish, ThisIndex) + 1
            End If
        End If
        If TaskFinishes(FFinish, x) >= dt And TaskFinishes(FFinish, x) < dt + 1 Then
            FinishesPerDate(FFinish, ThisIndex) = FinishesPerDate(FFinish, ThisIndex) + 1
        End If
    Next x
Next dt
Set p = Nothing


'Preview the data
For x = 1 To UBound(FinishesPerDate, 2)
    Debug.Print FinishesPerDate(DateValue, x), "BL: " & FinishesPerDate(BLFinish, x), "FF: " & FinishesPerDate(FFinish, x)
    'control/g


                    XlSheet.Cells(2, i).Value = FinishesPerDate(DateValue, x)
                    XlSheet.Cells(3, i).Value = FinishesPerDate(BLFinish, x)
                    XlSheet.Cells(4, i).Value = FinishesPerDate(FFinish, x)
                    XlSheet.Cells(5, i).Value = FinishesPerDate(ACFinish, x)
                    i = i + 1

Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Where to start?  some suggestions:

Comment: increment i within the loop.  Research "TimescaleData" - you will need to assign a TimescaleValues variable then pick through the individual values, by day, week, month or whatever is of interest to you.

Comment: Finally - what are you actually trying to acheive?  pjTaskTimescaledBaselineRemainingTasks is not a thing and its not obvious to me what you want it to be :-)

Comment: And - if you use Early binding (I'd only do so for development) you can take advantage of intellisence to see what methods and properties are available to you for each object

Comment: Hi @MalcolmFarrelle - Ultimatly I want to export data to enable me to create a burndown chart in Excel and not MS Project. For that I need timescaled data with the following feilds: Date, Baseline Remaining Tasks, Remaining Tasks, Remaining Actual Tasks. Thanks for your feed back all so far.

Comment: What do you mean by "Remaining Tasks" and  "Baseline Remaining Tasks"? These are not MS Project properties.  If you can describe in plain English what you are trying to acheive I will try to help.

Comment: Timescale data applies to a Task, Resource or Assignment.  It yields timephased data such as Cost, Work Baseline Work, CPI, etc for the Timescale units you select.  What do you want your burndown charts to show?  Please try to avoid technical terms (as you choose terms that don't exist) and lay out what you are trying to chart in plain English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suspense is killing me.  I'm not enturely sure what the OP wants, so I've taken a guess.  If the OP wants to know "How many tasks are baselined to finish and are forecast to finish on each of the days between the earliest (Forecast) [Finish] or [Baseline Finish] date and the latest (Foreacast) [Finish] or [Baseline Finish] date" then the following should sufice.  (TimeScaleData in the OP was a crimson kipper):

```
Sub GetFinishesPerDay()
'Malcolm Farrelle
Const DateValue = 0
Const BLFinish = 1
Const FFinish = 2
Dim TaskFinishes() As Date
Dim FinishesPerDate() As Variant
Dim t As Task
Dim p As Project
Dim i As Integer
Dim startdt As Date
Dim finishdt As Date
Dim dt As Date
Dim ThisIndex As Integer
ReDim TaskFinishes(2, 0)
ReDim FinishesPerDate(3, 0)
Set p = ActiveProject
startdt = p.Finish
finishdt = p.Start
For Each t In p.Tasks
    If Not t Is Nothing Then
        'Do not consider any "blank lines" in the project, these are not actually tasks and code will fail
        If Not t.Summary Then
            'Check the finish and baselinefinish dates and set the "startdt" and "finishdt"
            'variables with the earliest start and latest finish of the whole data set
            If t.Finish < startdt Then startdt = t.Finish
            If t.Finish > finishdt Then finishdt = t.Finish
            If t.BaselineFinish <> "NA" Then
                If t.BaselineFinish < startdt Then startdt = t.BaselineFinish
                If t.BaselineFinish > finishdt Then finishdt = t.BaselineFinish
            End If
            'Consider only non-summary tasks - if required add another check to exclude milestones
            ThisIndex = UBound(TaskFinishes, 2) + 1
            ReDim Preserve TaskFinishes(2, ThisIndex)
            If t.BaselineFinish <> "NA" Then TaskFinishes(BLFinish, ThisIndex) = t.BaselineFinish
            TaskFinishes(FFinish, ThisIndex) = t.Finish
        End If
    End If
Next t
'construct an array of Finishes and Baseline Finishes per date
For dt = Format(startdt, "dd/mmm/yy") To Format(finishdt, "dd/mmm/yy")
    'Using "Format" removes the "HH:MM" component of the itterating "dt" date
    ThisIndex = UBound(FinishesPerDate, 2) + 1
    ReDim Preserve FinishesPerDate(3, ThisIndex)
    FinishesPerDate(FFinish, ThisIndex) = 0
    FinishesPerDate(BLFinish, ThisIndex) = 0
    For i = 1 To UBound(TaskFinishes, 2)
        FinishesPerDate(DateValue, ThisIndex) = dt
        If TaskFinishes(BLFinish, i) <> 0 Then
            'task (i) has a baseline finish
            If TaskFinishes(BLFinish, i) >= dt And TaskFinishes(BLFinish, i) < dt + 1 Then
                'and it finishes on date "dt"
                FinishesPerDate(BLFinish, ThisIndex) = FinishesPerDate(BLFinish, ThisIndex) + 1
            End If
        End If
        If TaskFinishes(FFinish, i) >= dt And TaskFinishes(FFinish, i) < dt + 1 Then
            FinishesPerDate(FFinish, ThisIndex) = FinishesPerDate(FFinish, ThisIndex) + 1
        End If
    Next i
Next dt
Set p = Nothing
'Preview the data
For i = 1 To UBound(FinishesPerDate, 2)
    Debug.Print FinishesPerDate(DateValue, i), "BL: " & FinishesPerDate(BLFinish, i), "FF: " & FinishesPerDate(FFinish, i)
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Malcom (Crimson Kipper - love it lol)... I will have a look at this. It could be I was going about this the wrong way based on your thoughts. T

Comment: Hi Malcom... sorry for the delay but this was the first chance I had to look at the solution in depth. You are quite right that the timescaled data was the wrong approach and some thing I will consider in the future. The solution you gave me was ideal how ever and with a little change at the end I have been able to push in to my xls. Once again thank you for your time - it made the world of difference to an issue I have literally been banging my head with. I have also added an updated version at the top of this entry including actuals as well. Thank you for your help. Terran

Comment: Great I'm glad it helped. Feel free to add me on linked in and endorse me for MS Project VBA. Malcolm Farrelle